# Why do magnetic duct connections snap together so perfectly?

Tags: electromagnetism, home-experiment

An interesting video is floating around on Facebook that provides a good view of a dryer duct snapping together.  The wall magnet is fixed and flush with the wall.  Since the dryer hose is flexible, its magnet hangs an inch or two lower and at a different angle than the wall magnet.  As the dryer is being moved into position, when it gets close enough to the wall magnet, the hose magnet suddenly lifts up and snaps perfectly into place.

Mystified by the perfect centering of these two annuli, I attempted an explanation, saying it must be due primarily to the strength of the magnetic force and the shapes being identical.  One of my high school classmates then replied: "Magnetic alignment."  But doesn't this only describe what's going on at the atomic level?  Which explanation is more correct?  By the way, I'm pretty sure my classmate wasn't trying to make a pun! :)

Comment: I don't think that "magnetic alignment" is an argument. And also your "magnetic force" argument seams to be shady. The force argument explains the acceleration and therefore the path towards the stable final configuration, but it does not explain the final configuration. In fact, it's an energy argument, which explains the final configuration. If you understand what I mean, you might answer your question by yourself.

Comment: @Semoi I don't know very much about physics, but it's nice to at least know my classmate's answer probably wasn't any better than mine. :)

Comment: Honestly, this is your take-away message and your stopping point? Do you get my point about **argumentation**? I really believe that a good argument is worth more than a correct answer, because it gives me the opportunity to learn.

Comment: @Samoi if you are not aware of Tim Urban's *Wait But Why* blog, let me recommend this post specifically: https://waitbutwhy.com/2019/09/thinking-ladder.html  I got into a big argument with my attention bouncer just now about pursuing this matter further, but I won that argument, so here goes:  You wrote above that "The force argument explains ... *the path towards* the final configuration." (emphasis mine)  Isn't the final configuration *determined by* said path?

Comment: Of course you could try to solve the dynamics of the system. **If** you succeed you will obtain the correct result. However, this is a difficult task and you probably won't get a proper understanding of the result. In contrast, there exists the much simpler energy argument: The final state is the one with the lowest (potential) energy. When you are not interested in the path, you shouldn't bother about it. As "all" roads lead to the same result, the energy arguments skips them all together and jumps to the conclusion.